# Bootstrap Image Grid with 3 Images

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm still wrapping my head around bootstrap's grid system, and I'd like to set up a photo grid consisting of three images, with this layout. How would I go about it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of the grid system. You need to create a row to hold all of the sections. Then inside the row, create 2 columns, left and right. On the right column, create 2 rows.

So the structure should be like this:

```
- row
    - column
    - column
        - row
        - row
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="padding:100px; background:red;">
          1
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="row" style="padding:100px; background:blue;">
            2
          </div>
          <div class="row" style="padding:100px; background:gray;">
            3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I fill these blocks with an image with the image taking up the full space of each block? I've tried including them inline and background images and I can't seem to get them to display correctly.

Comment: Like this: [link](https://i.imgur.com/rhHNWK4.png)

Comment: You can remove the padding on the column, and from the inside of column or row, insert a img tag with styling of `width:100%`

Comment: Got it! [link](https://codepen.io/capturedghosts/pen/bGLywbX) Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Sure!, Good luck